# Format of size field in wasm sections?

Tags: webassembly

I am fighting a bug in my own webAssembly JS to wasm compiler. I am not sure if I have the size format correct and what the limits are

For example a data segment with 127 bytes

```
00 41 00 0b 7f ...data
            ^^ size 127 bytes
```

Then with 128 bytes

```
00 41 00 0b 8001 ...data
            ^^^^ size 128
```

I am guessing that the high bit if on indicates that there will be a byte following. That would mean that the next step would be

```
00 41 00 0b ff7f ...data
            ^^^^ size 16383

00 41 00 0b 808001 ...data
            ^^^^^^ size 16384
```

So the length is in nibit order (3 bytes 6 nibits) `103254` with nibits 1 and 3 having the top bit set such that looking at bits `S1110000 S3332222 A5554444` where S is always on and A is always off and numbers represent nibit bit order.

- Is this correct and what is the largest value that can be represented in this format?
- Is this the only size format?
- Is there a standard algorithm to convert from a Javascript Number representing length to this format as currently my solution seams very hacky?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wasm binary format uses [LEB128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128) format for all integer numbers. In the case of sizes specifically [unsigned LEB128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128#Unsigned_LEB128). However, unlike general LEB128s, Wasm imposes a maximum length, see [the specification](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/values.html#integers).

You can find plenty of sample implementations of LEB128 encoding/decoding on the Web, e.g., it's a 3-line function in the [Wasm reference interpreter](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/interpreter/binary/encode.ml#L52) (in OCaml).